# How to Create a Limacon of Pascal in a CAD drawing?

Tags: cad

How to Create a [Limacon of Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on) in a CAD drawing for extrusion etc? Need a .STEP file ultimately.

Comment: We don’t store .step files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be in OpenSCAD:

```
module limacon(a, b) {
    r = function(a, b, theta) a + b * sin(theta);

    polygon([for (t=[0 : 1 : 359]) 
        [r(a,b,t)*sin(t), r(a,b,t)*cos(t)]]);
};

// draw a limacon with the specified parameters:
limacon(3, 5);
```

With this, we can draw the 3D extruded polygon like this:

```
linear_extrude(5)
        limacon(3, 5);
```

Which results in a drawing like this:

[image]

From there, things get a little more tedious than you'd probably like. At least as far as I know, OpenSCAD can't export directly to a .STEP file, but you can import the OpenSCAD file into FreeCAD, then export the object to a .STEP file from there.

Comment: Very nice answer, I have another question here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60072/how-to-create-a-parabola-in-a-cad-drawing