# How to Create a parabola in a CAD drawing?

Tags: cad

How to Create a parabola in a CAD drawing?

How to create a parabola in a CAD drawing for extrusion etc? Need a .STEP file ultimately.
OpenScad would be optimal.

I tried this in fusion 360: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fusion360/comments/ejg226/accurate_parabolas_in_fusion_360/
But I could not figure out how to do the first step: "Create design parameters for your focus and radius."

Comment: This is going to depend on the CAD tool, so you may wish to _edit your title_ to say you're using Fusion 360.  Personally, I'd start by seeing if my CAD program supported splines.  Then I'd see if they document it well enough that I could just drop down some points such that the generated spline was a parabola (i.e., if the tool only supports 3rd-order parabolas and I can specify endpoints that are unconstrained in slope, then I could find a formula to go from a parabola to four points -- then I could drop those four points and draw the parabola as a spline).

Comment: Open SCAD and step seems to be diametriically opposite problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of code to draw points on a parabola with a sphere at each point computed on the parabola:

```
module parabola(left, right, steps, thickness = 0.3) {
    for (x = [left : (right-left)/steps : right]) 
        translate([x, x*x, 0]) sphere(thickness);
}

parabola(-5, 5, 200);
```

Produces a result like this:

[image]

If you want the points connected by "lines", you can (for example) draw a hull from each sphere to the next, something on this order:

```
hull() {
   translate(first_point) sphere(line_thickness);
   translate(second_point) sphere(line_thickness);
}
```

...but OpenSCAD doesn't have a "line" primitive, so you can't just draw a line from one point to the next.